# How to update data attribute in JSTREE?

Tags: javascript, jstree

I have some data for jstree.

```
             { "text": "some job name", 
                     "type": "job",
                            "id": 1200, 
                            "price": "0.00", 
                            "jobname": "somename", 
                            "time": "0.000", 
                            "jobtype": "12", 
                            "deletable":1, 
                            "archive":1,
                            "icon": "fa fa-angle-right   ",
                            "group": "2075"
                            }
```

I can change name, id. How I can change on-fly other attributes? 'archive', 'deletable'?

```
$($('#groups').jstree().get_selected(true)).attr('archive', 2);
```

Not working.

```
$($('#groups').jstree().get_selected(true)).attr('data-archive', 2);
```

Not working too

Comment: How are you changing name and id?

Comment: $('#groups').jstree("rename_node", node.id, data.text); API method

Comment: $('#groups').jstree("set_value", node.id, data.archive); won't work?

Comment: :-) is not API method

https://www.jstree.com/api/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

okey this is worked for me

```
$('#tree').jstree().get_selected(true)[0]['original'].archive = value
```

Answer (score 0):

xplo4d's answer not worked for me;

In version 3.3.11 this code worked for me :

```
var ref = $("#jstree").jstree(true);
var sel = ref.get_selected();
ref.get_node(sel)["li_attr"]["attributeName"] = value;
ref.edit(sel);
```