# jstree change data attribute (li_attr)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

I try to change a data-attribute on an existing node in jstree, but no answer i find worked for me.
I found this, didnt work: [How to update data attribute in JSTREE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58769017/how-to-update-data-attribute-in-jstree)

```
.jstree(true).get_node(item_id).li_attr.data-opened-before = true
```

I get the error: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment"
Can anybody help?

Comment: can you add complete code?

Comment: Im sorry, i cant. But i do use li_attr to add the attribute in the first place: li_attr: {"data-opened-before" : "false"}

I do this when i initiate the jstree and the data-attribute is drawn and visible in frontend sourcecode.